# NSURLSession's sharedSession is very slow. Is there a way to speed up dataTaskWithURL?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, https, nsurlsession

When I ping the exact same URL in a browser or with a terminal ping the response time is less than 300ms. When I make the request in the app with the code below it takes 3 seconds to get the response data. I even tried it with http://www.google.com and the response time takes 2-3 seconds to complete. Are there any tricks to get quicker responses when requesting data from a URL in Swift? What is going begind the scenes to make the request? Is there some way to warm up the connection before constructing the call?

**UPDATE**: If I call the function many times in a row it begins to respond very quickly(~200ms). That makes me believe that there is some sort of ramp up time to create the connection - where subsequent calls are lightning fast. It is an https call, but again I know it isn't the server because the ping and browser handle it in milliseconds. Is there some sort of known delay in iOS/Swift when opening an initial request?

```
 func phraseSearch(var text: String, completion: ([Translation])-> Void) {

    let urlString = baseAPIString + "/search?q=test"


    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let searchUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)


    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(searchUrl!) {

        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {


            let searchData: NSDictionary!
            let translationsData: NSArray!
            do {
                searchData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            } catch _ {
                searchData = NSDictionary()
            }

            translationsData = searchData["translations"] as! NSArray


            var translations = [Translation]()
            for translation in translationsData {
                let translation = Translation(data: translation as! NSDictionary)
                translations.append(translation)
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                completion(translations)
            })


        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

**UPDATE**: I added time stamps to show timing per this screenshot: [Screenshot with time stamps](https://www.evernote.com/l/AA5nQsirVRtFhIT6ecVtOjyvqIhlzMUER0Y)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Rob How are you timing the response? Maybe I can try that first so we have a baseline.

Comment: That is in seconds correct? I got 3.71592199802399
https://www.evernote.com/l/AA7FAMBGyANAnIM5irIMTeDAAFyhL2wBzQI

Comment: I added some more markers. 2 seconds from start to finish is still 1.7 seconds higher than any of my pings: https://www.evernote.com/l/AA5nQsirVRtFhIT6ecVtOjyvqIhlzMUER0Y

Comment: It is just under 1K (917b) https://www.evernote.com/l/AA6wM21_XQNN5a_VnJuWGyl3x6-PCea92D0

Comment: Here's something interesting. If I call the function many times in a row it begins to respond in milliseconds. So, I am starting to assume there is some sort of ramp up time to create the connection. It is an https call, but again I know it isn't the server because the ping and browser handle it in milliseconds. Is there some sort of known delay in iOS/Swift when opening an initial request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97101/discussion-between-rob-and-sean).

Comment: I call the function many times in a row it begins to respond in milliseconds.  --->This may be related with NSURLSession local cache.